# Multiple Firebase notifications with Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I created a Node.js file to send notifications with the help of FCM, I uploaded the file to the "Functions" section of Firebase, it works correctly, when it finds a change in the database it sends a notification to the devices.

The problem is that it sends the same notification too many times (between 3 and 10).

this is my code Node.js:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var request = require('request');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var API_KEY = "<KEY>"; 

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: "projectId",
    clientEmail: "clientEmail",
    privateKey: "privateKey"
  }),
  databaseURL: "https://database.firebaseio.com/"
});

exports.backendDeNotificaciones = functions.database.ref('/solicitudDeNotificaciones').onWrite(event => {


ref = admin.database().ref();
function EsperandoNotificaciones() 
{
 console.log("Esperando Notificaciones");
 var requests = ref.child('solicitudDeNotificaciones');
 requests.on('child_added', function(requestSnapshot)
 {
   var request = requestSnapshot.val();
   enviarNotificacion(
   request.username, 
   request.message,
   function() 
   {
    requestSnapshot.ref.remove();
   });
 }, function(error) 
  {
   console.error(error);
  });
};


function enviarNotificacion(username, message, onSuccess) {
  request({
   url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
   'Content-Type' :' application/json',
   'Authorization': 'key='+API_KEY
   },
  body: JSON.stringify({
   notification: {
    title: message
   },
   to : '/topics/TOPIC_NAME'
  })
  }, function(error, response, body) {
   if (error) { console.error(error); }
   else if (response.statusCode >= 400) { 
   console.error('Error de HTTP: '+response.statusCode+' — '+response.statusMessage); 
  }
 else {
  onSuccess();
  console.log("Notificación Enviada :)");
 }
 });
}
EsperandoNotificaciones();

});
```

Comment: Instead of firing every time there is a child added, maybe you should send once every hour, so you take a snapshot of the collection every hour then send it; **or maybe you could keep track to (whom and the number of times) the message was sent**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time someone writes a notification request to the database, you read all notifications requests from the database, send them, and delete them. This may lead to race conditions when you receive a new notification request while processing another one.

You should instead simply respond to each individual notification request. This also nicely simplifies your code:

```
exports.backendDeNotificaciones =
functions.database.ref('/solicitudDeNotificaciones/{messageId}').onCreate(event => {
    var request = event.data.val();
    enviarNotificacion(
      request.username, 
      request.message,
      function() {
        event.data.ref.remove();
      });
    }, function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Wow! the author of the article that I tried to follow!
I am embarrassed to say that I have tried to modify my code with the help you have provided, but I have not succeeded, I am new to learning JavaScrip. I would be very grateful if you would show me the correct way in which I would have to add the code.

Comment: What's the problem when you use the snippet I shared just now? Does it give an error? If so, what's the error message?

Comment: My mistake was mistakenly inserting the code, perhaps because of the fatigue.
I have rewritten it and it worked perfectly.
**Thank you very much for the help, I am very grateful!**